# How to convert timedelta (with days) to total seconds

Tags: python, python-datetime

I need to covert Time Elapsed to total seconds. I used three functions with no luck.

First function:

```
ny["Time Elapsed"].time()
```

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'time'

Second function:

```
ny["Time Elapsed"].total_seconds()
```

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Third function:

```
ny["Time Elapsed"](int)
```

> TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

a picture of the dataframe is attached. [image]

I am trying to convert the time duration in the time elapsed column to seconds. The name of the dataframe is "ny".

Comment: Ask yourself this question... What object type is *ny["Time Elapsed"]* ?

Comment: codist it is timedelta, the problem I cannot convert it to seconds

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4046632). "a picture of the dataframe" is of no use at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem arises because you are not using the .dt accessor. You should use:

```
ny['tot_s'] = ny["Time Elapsed"].dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: thank you all for your insight. User19077881 your answer worked best for me, do we have to call dt every time we call total_seconds?

Comment: Think of it in another way: `.dt.total_seconds()` is the pandas function to convert a TimeDelta Series into a number of seconds (in fact the number is a float but could be converted to int as required). It is similar to using `.str.split()` on a column holding strings. .dt and .str are known as accessors in Pandas. which you can look up in the ref docs. The Python functions total_seconds() and strip() cannot be directly applied to a Pandas Series and should be thought of as different functions.